# Component file not found ierror

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a component that is included in a controller using the below syntax

```
var $components  = array("Razorpay");
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
 [MissingComponentException] Component class RazorpayComponent could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'RazorpayComponent',
  'plugin' => false,
)
```

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and the error is only in the live environment and when I try to hit the same in wamp then the error doesn't persists.

Comment: How have you added this component? Seems like maybe an autoloader wasn't updated in the live environment, or the dependency itself is missing?

Comment: Yes I have added the component inside the ```Component``` folder which is inside the ```Controller``` folder

Comment: See if the name of the component is correct or not even the case of each letter

Comment: This is a component that you built, or you downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: The issue is resolved! I just misplaced the name of the component from RazorPay to Razorpay